# Nlog: File target with file name based on request header (with minlevel="Info")

Tags: .net-core, nlog

I'm trying to write to a file with fileName based on scopeproperty:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="errorsLogFile" fileName="c:\inor_logs\${scopeproperty:domainName}\error-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="" />

 <target xsi:type="File" name="requestBegin" fileName="c:\inor_logs\${scopeproperty:domainName}\request-begin-${shortdate}.log"
               layout="" />
```

I have those rules:

```xml
<rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="errorsLogFile" />

    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics" minlevel="Info" writeTo="requestBegin">
      <filters defaultAction="Ignore">
        <when condition="contains('${message}','starting') and (contains('${uppercase:${aspnet-request-method}}','POST') or contains('${uppercase:${aspnet-request-method}}','PUT') or contains('${uppercase:${aspnet-request-method}}','DELETE'))" action="Log" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
  </rules>
```

The first file is getting `${scopeproperty:domainName}`'s value and works correctly.

But the second file target `requestBegin` is getting an empty value for `${scopeproperty:domainName}`!

Comment: See NLog ScopeContext examples for how to use https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeProperty-Layout-Renderer#example (Notice logging must happen inside the scope). Maybe you are looking for NLog GlobalDiagnosticsContext https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/GDC-Layout-Renderer

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4992